# Can't move Taskbar

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar

My friend was on my laptop and accidently moved my taskbar from bottom to top of my screen. I've tried grabbing the taskbar and move it back down. I can grab it alright but as soon as I begin moving my mouse down with it, it releases the toolbar. Is there any other way of getting the toolbar back to the bottom?

Thank you

Toshiba Laptop
OS XP

Comment: please provide more details, e.g. operating system version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Right click the taskbar
2. Uncheck "Lock the Taskbar"
3. Drag your taskbar around the edges
   of the screen (Erratically move your
   mouse if it's "stuck")
4. Check "Lock the Taskbar"

---

As Dodi points out below in the comments (he solved it himself), you find the answer on one of the "taskbar fixes" on this [site](http://www.kellys-korner-xp.com/xp_tweaks.htm). (It was a registry problem.)

Comment: It is unlocked, the mouse does not get stuck it just rreleases the taskbar as soon as I begin to move it down.

Comment: Try to move it the right/left edge of the screen and then move it down.

Comment: @Dodi What do you mean by "does not get stuck and releases the taskbar"? Do you *want* the mouse to get stuck?? That doesn't make any sense. Also, how do you know it "releases the taskbar"? Does your cursor change (arrow to thumb, etc)? If so, it shouldn't since it should stay at arrow all the time. There's no way to tell if the taskbar is "released".

Comment: @muntoo -1 for lame steps in how to unlock the taskbar and move the taskbar. Putting it in steps is unnecessary. You could've said Have you unlocked the taskbar? as a comment. Or if as an answer, you could've said right click it choose unlock, then try moving it. This isn't for people that are so computer illiterate.Also, where he said the mouse doesn't get stuck,and you thought he wanted it to get stuckHe is clear,obviously he doesn't want the mouse to get stuck, don't be a silly billy.He is describing what happens.His taskbar doesn't move, and that's not because the mouse is getting stuck.

Comment: @barlop OK... but how does he know the taskbar is "released"? A definition of "released" would be nice.

Comment: if you just had one vote I wouldn't have downvoted, but for an answer describing in steps, how to unlock and move the taskbar, that's far too lame to deserve 2 votes. And it's unnecessary and not concise. AND he said his friend moved it and he said it releases the taskbar so it sounds like maybe it is unlocked.  And lo and behold, it was unlocked according to him

Comment: @barlop I still don't get the "releases the taskbar" part. @Dodi How about a screen capture to help this "silly billy" understand? :P

Comment: that's a fair request.. could be it jumps back..  I see on my system there's no movement, so to jump back it'd have to have moved there.

Comment: I have moved taskbars back to the bottom of my screen before. You get two lines with the arrow going both directions and you hold it  and take it to the bottom of your screen and release it. The cursor stays with the two lines with the arrows going in opposite directions until you release it at the bottom of your screen and your taskbar will then be  where it belongs. The reason I know that the mouse is releasing the taskbar is because once I begin to move the mouse down the screen the two lines with the arrows disappears and only my mouse arrow is visible. Is that clear enough?

Comment: @Dodi No, the "double-black-arrows" happen when you're "resizing" the taskbar. At least, that's what happens in Vista. I'm sure it's the same in XP. Can you give us a screenshot? Press PrtScrn on your keyboard. Then, go to Paint, and paste.

Comment: ok will do right now

Comment: i have the screen shot but how do I upload it to here?

Comment: @Dodi Jones  How long have you had XP? i've had it for almost 10 years. The black arrows as muntoo says, are for resizing.  You shouldn't be talking like you know how to move a taskbar when clearly you don't. You should have said you're a complete ignoramous. Because it's bad for the community if people assume that by default. See that pink dot, that is a place you can click and hold to move the taskbar. Do it and move the mouse cursor all the way to a different side  http://i56.tinypic.com/ofvnfl.jpg  You do not want a resize icon or the start menu popping up.

Comment: See that pic in my previous comment, that pink dot is where to click and hold, aim there. If you can use a urinal, you can do that. For goodness sake you shouldn't get a start menu popping up, or a resize icon.  If you manage that, it's progress.

Comment: [Here is a pic of what I do on Vista.](http://i.imgur.com/EX8nz.png) (They made the start button so sensitive that the area ~15px around it is also considered start button zone.)

Comment: @barlop I have never used a urinal and dont plan on it in the future. And that is exactly where I'm clicking to try and move it down. And I've been using XP for as long as it's been out. The point is that it should move it but it does not. Thank you all for your suggestions. And your sarcasm.

Comment: @Dodi Do these help? [LINK 1](http://www.google.ca/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=taskbar+registry) [LINK 2](http://i.imgur.com/Juj4m.png) It may be some registry problem.

Comment: @muntoo thank you. It was a registry problem. Repaired it and now taskbar is where it belongs.

Comment: @Dodi Jones  Other people might have the problem. You should include here precisely what the fix was. So that it helps others.

Comment: I found my solution here http://www.kellys-korner-xp.com/xp_tweaks.htm

Comment: @Dodi Which one was it?

Comment: I went in and removed this registry key that was preventing me from modifying my taskbar. sorry for the delay in answer. had a family emergency. open Regedit and go to path: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\Explorer
 DWORD key: LockTaskBar  value to 1